# It seems like my module is not loading and saving String arrays properly. Why?

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with my methods for a school assignment which are supposed to load and save String arrays to a file. It seems like it does not save or load properly. For example, I saved a string of "ok" in a file, let's call it x. Then I rerun the app and changed the path to a directory and it read the string "ok" from it even though it wasn't initially saved the directory and the directory shouldn't be allowed anyways. I really don't know how to solve it and I tried to manipulate the code but I do not know what causes it so it's hard to think of a solution.

Some details on my task:

- have to use File Output/Input Stream and Object Output/Input Stream
- question and answer strings have to be initialized to 0 size if the path is empty/is a dir/ file not found
- take answer and question string from textfield, save it to a file and read the existing ones from the file
- question and answer string arrays have to be in a separate class

Code:

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class App2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  JPanel mpanel, qpanel, apanel, bpanel, upanel;
  JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3;
  JButton jb;
  JLabel jl1, jl2, jl3;
  String path;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    App2 object = new App2();
    System.out.println("app init/ array size:" + QAData.question.length);
  }

  App2() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(400, 200);
    this.setTitle("App2");
    mpanel = new JPanel();
    this.add(mpanel);
    mpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    qpanel = new JPanel();
    mpanel.add(qpanel);
    apanel = new JPanel();
    mpanel.add(apanel);
    upanel = new JPanel();
    mpanel.add(upanel);
    bpanel = new JPanel();
    mpanel.add(bpanel);

    jl1 = new JLabel("Question: ");
    qpanel.add(jl1);
    tf1 = new JTextField(20);
    tf1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);
    qpanel.add(tf1);
    tf1.addActionListener(this);

    jl2 = new JLabel("Answer: ");
    apanel.add(jl2);
    tf2 = new JTextField(20);
    tf2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);
    apanel.add(tf2);
    tf2.addActionListener(this);

    jl3 = new JLabel("Path: ");
    upanel.add(jl3);
    tf3 = new JTextField(20);
    tf3.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);
    upanel.add(tf3);
    tf3.addActionListener(this);

    jb = new JButton("Update");
    jb.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
    bpanel.add(jb);
    jb.addActionListener(this);


    this.setVisible(true);


  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == tf3)
      path = tf3.getText();

    if (e.getSource() == jb) {
      load();
      save();
      tf1.setText("");
      tf2.setText("");
    }
  }


  void load() {
    try {
      File file = new File("path");
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
      boolean fileIsOk = file.isFile() && !(tf3.getText().equals("")) && !(file.isDirectory());
      if (!fileIsOk) {
        QAData.question = new String[0];
        QAData.answer = new String[0];
        System.out.println("size 0 applied");
      } else {

        QAData.question = (String[]) ois.readObject();
        QAData.answer = (String[]) ois.readObject();
      }
      ois.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("No such class found");
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("I/O exception during the load");
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      System.out.println("The object you are trying to read has the null value");
      e.printStackTrace();


    }
  }

  void save() {
    try {
      File file = new File("path");
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
      boolean fileIsOk = file.isFile() && !(tf3.getText().equals("")) && !(file.isDirectory());
      if (fileIsOk) {
        QAData.question = Arrays.copyOf(QAData.question, QAData.question.length + 1);
        QAData.question[(QAData.question.length - 1)] = tf1.getText();
        QAData.answer = Arrays.copyOf(QAData.answer, QAData.answer.length + 1);
        QAData.answer[(QAData.answer.length - 1)] = tf2.getText();
        oos.writeObject(QAData.question);
        oos.writeObject(QAData.answer);
      }

      oos.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("I/O exception during the save");
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      System.out.println("The object you are trying to save has the null value");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  static class QAData implements Serializable {
    static String[] question = new String[0];
    static String[] answer = new String[0];
  }

}
```

Comment: Your load method will not compile, due to an extra `}`, so I assume it is not the actual code you’re trying to run.  Please edit your question and replace that code with the actual code you’re running.  Remove all `catch (NullPointerException e)` blocks;  if you are dereferencing null, it is an error in your code that should be fixed, not caught and swept under the rug.  And all other catch blocks need to call `e.printStackTrace();`, so that if something goes wrong, you will know exactly where and why.

Comment: Did you get an exception when saving or loading the file? Tip: include the exception error message when printing in the `catch` clause.

Comment: @VGR I pasted my code in and added the e.printStackTrace()

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I didn't get an exception